# Where is "$public_key" saved in?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Where is this `$public_key` saved in? I mean I want to change the value of it

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k={{ $public_key }}"`

Comment: that's just a variable. if you want to change the value of it you can assign value as `$public_key = 'blah';`

Comment: Yout should assign it in your controller and pass it to the view.  Need to see your controller method that loads this view if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variable, that you need to provide.

Usually, such information as public/private keys is better if it is saved in the `.env` file (since this file contains constants that are related to your environment) and then you can use it like `env('SOMETHING_PUBLIC_KEY')`.

This said, in your case above, the `$public_key` is a variables that is passed to the view from a controller's method.

```
return view('something', [
 'public_key' => '...'
])
```